# Linking same page in html but url get index.html/#[object%20Object]

Tags: html

I am new in website development. I have problem is navigation bar never I am click to navbar just home , about, service, contact there are in navigation bar if I am click to about that time to URL set  please my problem this #[object%20Object]
I don't understand please help me

```
<li><a href="#welcome">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact-us">Contact</a></li>

Same page link IDs used

<div id="welcome"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="service"></div>
<div id="contact-us"></div>
```

Please Help me

Comment: Add your code to https://codepen.io/ so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Try following code hope it will help

```html
    <li><a href="#welcome">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact</a></li>
    
    Same page link IDs used
    
    <div id="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <a href="http://blinkhtml.com">Blink Html</a>
    In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.</div>
    <div id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <a href="http://blinkhtml.com">Blink Html</a>
    In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.</div>
    <div id="service">
    <h1>Service</h1>
    In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.</div>
    <div id="contact-us">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.In CSS, "id" is a selector that is used to designate an area that a link should point to, similar to anchor in HTML. The nice thing about using id is you can create a link to any element on the page, rather than only the top or bottom. In the following sections, you'll see how to apply id to an HTML tag, and then how to link to it. This example will link to the opening paragraph at the top of this page.</div>
```